# Cómo establecer un rango numérico fijo en la creación de tablas de una BD en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Estoy creando una base de datos que almacena información sobre tiendas de aplicaciones móviles, tengo dos entidades (aplicaciones y usuarios) que tienen relación (descargar). Al ser una relación N:N se creará una tabla nueva de la relación descargar en la que quiero meter el atributo de puntuación, para que los usuarios cuando se descarguen la aplicación puedan puntuarla del 1 al 5. Aquí viene la cuestión, no sé cómo definir en mysql que solo pueda elegir el número 1,2,3,4 o 5, y no ningún otro ni introducir una letra por ejemplo.

Había pensado con `NUMERIC(1,0)` pero claro, se podrían introducir números del 1 al 9. Pensé en si podía haber alguna función SET o LIMIT dentro de la creación de base de datos pero no sé dónde ponerla ni si me funcionará. ¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de cómo podría hacerlo?

Os dejo por aquí el código que hice para la tabla de la relación:

```
CREATE TABLE DESCARGAR(
codUser SMALLINT,
codApp SMALLINT,
Puntuacion NUMERIC(1,0),
Comentarios VARCHAR(2000),
PRIMARY KEY (codUser, codApp),
FOREIGN KEY (codUser) REFERENCES Usuarios(codUser)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (codApp) REFERENCES Aplicaciones(codApp)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Me gustaría cambiar el dominio NUMERIC(1,0) que le di a Puntuacion, por otro que sea más exacto y adecuado para establecer un rango entre 1-5 como comenté anteriormente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dispones de la cláusula CHECK que te permite restringir los valores de un campo.

El ejemplo de esta página con el campo Age seguro que te ayuda

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp

en tu caso será algo así:
`CHECK(Puntuacion >= 1 AND Puntuacion<=5)`